# How do I solve this system of equations using back substitution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$$
\begin{cases}
-x_5+x_4=3\\
-x_5+2x_4+x_3=4\\
3.5x_4+5x_3+2x_3+2x_2+x_1=3.5
\end{cases}
$$
I know how to back substitute to solve for systems where you go you 1 equation down and there is an one extra varible, however with this system there are two extra varibles. How do I solve it then?

I am only just learning about matrices so please use simple language

Comment: Consider $x_1$ and $x_2$ as constants

Comment: A no-brainer way would be to represent the system as a matrix equation $AX=B$ and then using the formula $X=A^{-1}B$. Granted that it would take a lot of time and computations, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas do not understand the terminology sorry

Comment: Typo? 3rd equation has $x_3$ twice, no $x_5$. Please edit as appropriate.

Comment: I say, PLEASE EDIT.

Answer (score 2):

Backward substitution corresponds to $x_n, x_{n-1}, \ldots x_2, x_1$ in turn. First we see that $x_5$ is a free variable. Then from the first equation we have
$$x_4 = 3 + x_5$$
From the second equation we have
$$x_3 = 4 - 2x_4 + x_5 = -2 - x_5$$
Then we see that $x_2$ is also a free variable. From the last equation we have
$$x_1 = 3.5 - 2x_2 - 2x_3 - 5x_4 - 3.5x_5 = -7.5 - 2x_2 - 5.5x_5$$

Answer (score 1):

considering $x_1,x_2$ as parameters, the system become:
$$
\begin{cases}
-x_5+x_4=3\\
-x_5+2x_4+x_3=4\\
3.5x_4+5x_3+2x_3=3.5-2x_2-x_1
\end{cases}
$$
Subtracting the first equation from the second we find:
$$
x_4+x_3=1 \Rightarrow x_3=1-x_4
$$
and substituting in the third equation we find 
$$
x_4=1+\dfrac{2x_2+x_1}{1.5}
$$
this means that we can give any values to $x_1$ and $x_2$  and we always have a value for $x_4$.

Now using $x_4$ we find the values of $x_3$ and $x_5$ from the other equations.